# Transform multiple sheets in dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Silly Question - How to improve this code??

```
my_data1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 1)

my_data2 <- read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 2)

my_data3 <- read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 3)

my_data4 <- read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 4)
```

k = list(my_data1,my_data2,my_data3,my_data4) %>% reduce(left_join, by = "Município")

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the `sheet` number and read it into a `list` and `reduce` by joining them

```
library(purrr)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
k <- map(1:4, 
 ~ read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", 
              sheet = .x)) %>%
         reduce(left_join, by  = "Município")
```

Comment: Thank you, much better!

Answer (score 1):

Less clean than the answer above but you could also merge or join all the datafames, depending on if the columns are the same:

```
df <- merge(read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 1) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 2) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 3) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 4))
```

You can change `merge()` for any of the joins, depending upon your goals.

You should fill in the `(...)` with whichever columns you want to merge by, or completely remove the `by()` like I have above. I put dummy columns in the `by()`.

```
df <- merge(read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 1) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 2) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 3) %>% 
  read_excel("C:/Users/farj0/Downloads/Pilares_ranking_clp.xlsx", sheet = 4), 
  by = c("Col1", "Col2"))
```

The same `by()` statement will work for the `join()` function as well. If you have a ton of sheets, this may get annoying.